# Window.Current.Dispatcher is null at design time / in Blend. Can I get a reference to a Blend / designer CoreDispatcher object?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I have multiple ListViews and GridViews bound to Observables collections that implement ISupportIncrementalLoading.  The trouble is, in the implementation of ISupportIncrementalLoading you need to access Window.Current.Dispatcher.

At design time or in Blend Window.Current.Dispatcher is null and this crashes the designer completely.  Does anyone know if it's possible to get a reference to a different dispatcher in the Blend / VS designer environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet, and this is not exactly what you are looking for but I've been using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid getting NullReferenceExceptions and the like from occuring when using the Designer in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will have to code things differently between the designer and runtime environments. thanks